# Keeping PHP Includes Secure

Tags: php, security

My website file structure currently looks like this:

- marketplace.php
- cats.php

On marketplace.php I have a 4 categories which link to `$_GET` variables (e.g marketplace.php?cat=[1-4]).

On the top of the script for marketplace.php, I have a `if` statement that looks for the `cat` variable, checks if it is above zero, and so on.

If `cat` contains a number greater than zero, it will include cats.php and then show data according to that category number.

How do i make it so that people cannot go to cats.php by entering it in their browser?

Comment: what's wrong with direct call to the cat.php?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel They'll be expecting that

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `cats.php` out of the document root, but keep it on the include path.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you want to restrict users to access the included files (core files).

You can restrict them via .htaccess, or eventually define a constant (IN_APP), which will be checked in every file included. If constant isn't defined, just give an error to the user (404) that says the page doesn't exist

Comment: This is a common approach used by CMS's. It allows you easily block access and doesn't require access to a location outside the docroot (not all hosting gives you locations outside the docroot).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways do do this. If .htaccess is enabled on your server you could use it to block access to cat.php, or block access to an entire folder and put all your includes in there.

You could also put cat.php outside your web root (above `public_html` or whatever your folder is called).

Answer (score 0):

Most common and simple way. Define a constant in your main file

```
define('MY_APP_IS_RUNNING', true);
```

And secure the include by adding

```
if(!defined('MY_APP_IS_RUNNING') {
   die('This is a include file not for public access');
}
```

A little old school, but works.

**Edit**

The Basic idea is, all your includes /private files depend on a constant you define in your public script. If and only if this constant is defined your includes will execute.

in marketplace.php you would write

```
define('MY_APP_IS_RUNNING', true);
include_once 'cat.php';
```

and your cat.php will simply look whether 'MY_APP_IS_RUNNING' is defined or not. This will add basic security to your scripts and prevent direct external calls.

Comment: can you please explain this in more detail, i do not really understand. Sorry im not advanced with PHP.