# How to prevent direct access to php pages through URL

Tags: php, include

I have index.php that include pages like

```
<?php

define('MyConst', TRUE);

include_once('template/header.php');

if (!empty($_GET['action'])) {  
    $action = $_GET['action'];   
    $action = basename($action);   
    include("template/$action.php");   
} else { 
    include("template/main.php"); 
} 

include_once('template/footer.php'); 

?>
```

With in a template directory I have main.php which has link to other pages like page1.php, page2.php.

```
<a href="?action=page1">Goto page 1</a>
<a href="?action=page2">Goto page 2</a>
```

How could I prevent users form accessing pages directly typing "http://mydomain.com/?action=page1" on the URL? And redirect them to main.php if they have done it?

Comment: Use htaccess to redirect your request

Comment: This cannot be done in a good way. What is your goal with this - security?

Comment: Only possible solution I see is to use sessions. Save the info whether the user visited main.php before or not into the session, and check it in your index.php before delivering content.

Comment: Will this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file

Answer (score 1):

You can not. What you want is simply not possible.

For the server side there is no way to know whether an URL is typed or clicked.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer (ignoring the possibility of checking the referer, which can be forged.)

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think what the OP wants (in spirit, if not the letter) could be done by generating random IDs when outputting the links in his template. Whether all this is necessary at all is a different question of course - this smells like an XY question

Comment: I thought about CSRF token for a moment. But I didn't think that was what OP was after. Then again who knows ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the thing you want is to prevent the user to access `http://example.org/?action=page1` unless they came from `http://example.org/?action=main`. To do that, you must be able to detect whether they came from `http://example.org/?action=main`. The safest way to do that is to generate some random value that you associate to the users when they access `http://example.org/?action=main` and to check whether there is a correct value associated to the users when they want to access `http://example.org/?action=page1`. If not, they tried to access that page directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check for HTTP_REFERER and if it is not pointing to right values (like your meny page) then redirect user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this, On your index.php :

```
session_start();
if(! isset($_GET['action']))
{
   $_SESSION['pageAccess'] = true; # Set the key whatever you want
}
```

then under that script (we need that session_start() used twice) :

```
if(isset($_GET['action']))
{
  if(! isset($_SESSION['pageAccess']) || ! $_SESSION['pageAccess'])
     exit('There is no direct access allowed.');
}
```

Hope this help, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Question:

There are two approaches that you can follow:

1. Use `HTTP_REFFRER` and check on desired page if User is coming from the page u wanted. IF he is accessing the direct URL then show him error page.
2. Use `$_SESSION` but this approach can be harmful as `SESSION` will always be there untill browser / instance closed.

So better to go for 1st approach.
And also as per Pehaa, you can not check id URL is typed

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to your domain home if 'HTTP_REFERER' not include your server

```
<?php 
    //Avoid url direct access
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'yourdomain.com') !== FALSE) { 
     //Your code
    } else { 
        echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=https://yourdomain.com" />'; 
        die(); 
    }
?>
```