# how to put php files out of webroot

Tags: php, .htaccess, root

how can i know where is my web root folder ? 
and how to put folders out of web root folder? 
and how to test that they are not accessible from outside ?

the structure of my hosting is like this:

```
www.website.com :

public_html/
includes /
logs/
```

...

is it enough to protect includes folder and logs folder with htaccess? and are they out of web root in this case?

i know that $server[document root] provide the root of my website , but i am confused about how to put files out of it , any help would be welcome , thanks for all

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Why do you want to "put files out of webroot"? You don't need to worry about people downloading php files from the webserver, if someone requests one, the file is executed, not sent back in the response

Comment: Not sure on what you're trying to accomplish, But if you want to "put files out of webroot" just to "protect" them i'd advise you another way. You can just prevent them from being executed directly with a simple check. This answer may guide you http://stackoverflow.com/a/409515/2600397

Comment: It's `public_html` and not `public html`

Comment: as i understand that www.website.com is the web root itself , i want to get one folder up by adding this in my code ../ , so when i put php code one folder up it can only be included and not server by apache

Comment: i have seen many people that say they can hack php code using backtrack or something else , and the code want be secure unless it is out of root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your files are currently in the public web root folder.

The 'inside' of your root is your `publichtml/`. Everything you place in there will be publicly accessible.
The name of your root can vary from host to host, often `public_html` or `httpdocs`.

The 'outside' is one directory up. But remember some hosts do not give enough permissions.

You cannot test documents outside your root, because they are not accessible. Only something like PHP can access those files. That's why you do not place your img/JS/CSS files outside the root cause they need direct access.
You can however serve them through your PHP.

Comment: It's `public_html/` and not `publichtml/`

Comment: Well from my experience this changes from host to host, so I just copied what the OP had.

Comment: it's a Linux system and Apache server related document root. "space" in file/folder names is not an valid on linux system (if you do then you will have to escape it -- and may cause problem)

Comment: yes i know that i can not access files out of root , but i can include them , my question here is how to get one folder up if the command ../ dose not exist

Comment: Can you explain? Simply including `require_once('../test.php')` will fail? What is the error?

Comment: i have no access to that directory all i see in my host is www.website.com and its subfolders there is no folder else

Comment: Try discussing this issue with your hosting company.