# Load PHP pages only from Index.php

Tags: php, require

I have this newly created web page with a Index that loads with `require` the different parts of my web, depending on where you are located (home, contact, about, etc). My problem is that if a user types in the URL `/contact.php` this "module" will load up and give errors and I don't want that to happen. Can I block the access to all this small modules (contact.php, about.php, etc) and only be able to load them from `index.php` ? Is there anyway I can do that without touching the `.htaccess` file? Or would you recommend me editing this file too and block user access to them only to have an added layer of security? Can I still have access to the files from my `index.php` if I block them in `.htaccess` ?

Thanks.

Comment: You coded it bad. It shouldn't matter if they go directely to the url

Comment: Take a look at this question. The solution proposed there might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file

Comment: You can place that file outside the public domain and use an absolute path to that file, which is one option.

Comment: @hanleyhansen I found a good solution on that link that uses a constant and I will use that since it seems to be easy and very secure. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below functionality:

In your index.php file put below code at top before inclusion of other files:

```
define('_ANYUNIQUESTRING',"1");
```

In all other files, put below code at top:

```
defined('_ANYUNIQUESTRING') or die('Restricted access');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for. Do I have to use the underscore on the name of the constant?

Answer (score 2):

You can store these pages outside out the public_html folder so that only the server can access them.

If your public files are here

```
/home/user/public_html
```

Store the pages here

```
/home/user/pages
```

Then use the full path to require them.

Comment: I used something similar, I placed them in `../public_html/modules` and inside placed a `.htaccess` file with the code `Deny from all` and it works perfect. Thanks.