# prevent direct execution of php file

Tags: php

I have a php file for frontend. In this file there are few forms.

```
<form name="add3" method="post" id="add3" name="add3" action="add_exec.php" role="form">
</form>
```

now you can see in action **add_exec.php**. I want this file not to be execute directly.

I don't want to use **.htaccess** to achieve this.

Is there anything else we can do to prevent direct execution of `add_exec.php` file.

Thanks

Edit:

I am not looking for htaccess answer. If my file is in form action attribute then it will consider as include or not? If no then how can i prevent the execution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file

Comment: thanks for your comment. my question is if we use filename in action section, then does it will consider as include? because i do checked those SO questions.

Comment: @dagon I have updated the question. Can you please advice.

Comment: add_exec.php is 'executed' when the form is submitted. if you dont want some one typing its url in the browser, check that it has been sent form inputs

Comment: Perhaps if you explained the scenario your very obtuse question may make sense. Simple answer delete add_exec.php. It wont execute then

Comment: Thanks Dagon. I am checking that form inputs. But I want some specific error msg or error page to show. Because if form inputs are empty then i think it will give error like fill all fields or specific fields.

Comment: You want to use javascript then. But it sounds like you are a novice using javascript as your form validator only acts as a warning it will not prevent that php file from being executed with bad input data

Comment: @DeveloperChris Scenario is very simple i don't want execution of add_exec.php executed in url browser. add_exec.php will call by form only.

Comment: No  i am not looking for javascript solution.

Comment: you dont want the php to execute. you dont want a redirect in .htaccess you don't want javascript client side processing. clearly you want the form to do nothing at all. If you want just the fields simply remove the form element wrapper

Comment: add_exec.php can output any error you like.

Comment: @Dagon Agree with you i think i need to add something like if all fields are empty in post then redirect to index page.

Comment: First i will try schellingerht answer.

Comment: told you that 20 minutes ago - sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent accessing a resource (file, image, js, etc) hosted in web server by modifying web server configuration file. In Apache web server, it can be done using apache2.conf or .htaccess file.

```
<Files add_exec.php>
    Order allow, deny
    Deny from all
</ Files>
```

If it is not restricted by web server, it can be accessed from direct resource address like below. 
http://example.com/add_exec.php

But your scenario, POST data should receive to add_exec.php, it should prevent GET method only. So you can check if it is GET or POST and then process your form data.

In your add_exec.php file

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    exit();
}

// process your form
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check and let you know. Voted Up.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the request type:

Check on the top of add_exec.php the request method:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    exit('No access!');
```

Or:

```
if (!isset($_POST['specific_element_from_form']))
    exit('No access!');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sure will do that, i will check it and after that will mark it as answer. Now i got -2. hahaha