# How to prevent to direct access of PHP pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to **prevent direct access** of my PHP pages. I tried running "**.htaccess**", but it is not running. There are so many pages in my project. but I want in some of them. My PHP pages are:
example1.php
example2.php

My "**.htaccess**" code is:

```
     Options +FollowSymlinks
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule    ^/?example/([0-9]+)$    exam-ple.php    [NC,L]
```

If it is OK, then why it is not running.
I want any type of solution.

Comment: Put the files outside the web-root

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent direct access to a php include file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file)

Comment: Deny From all. It denied access from everything. I want these pages should accessible only through hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this code in the top-most part of your PHP page.

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Comment: It works but it also prevent access from anchor tag.

Comment: what is "BASEPATH" here?

Comment: Sorry for that. It was a global var I used that points to the system base path.  You can defined your own BASEPATH and use it to check to accept or deny direct access to a PHP file. This is a common process that is being used by most applications like CodeIgniter, Joomla, WordPress, etc.