# Correct relative paths for require_once()

Tags: php, path, require-once

I wish to better understand which is the safer way to specify `require` paths in the following cases. Please, tell me if some is wrong.

```
main.php
includes
|--afile.php
|--bfile.php
classes
|--aclass.php
|--bclass.php
```

`main.php` must include `afile.php`, so I put in `main.php`

```
require_once('includes/afile.php');
```

`afile.php` must include `aclass.php`, so I put in `afile.php`

```
require_once('../classes/aclass.php');
```

`aclass.php` must include `bclass.php`, so I put in `aclass.php`

```
require_once('bclass.php');
```

I was wondering if it is correct. I do not mean simply "correct", because I know that it works — I tried — but if this is the best approach. For example, if in future I move a file from a folder to another, I should change all paths in require instruction. If I forget one, I get an error. I was wandering if there is a way to write require so that it always know where is the root.

Looking for best practice.

Thank you in advance.

PS (Follow on EDIT) I found a way that seems to work: that is,

```
define("ROOT_DIR",__DIR__)
```

in my main.php and use `ROOT_DIR` in all other PHP files. It works even if I move files. There is any reason why I should not use that approach? Suggestions?

Comment: _"Is that correct?"_ - test it, and you will found out. `require` will throw a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error, when it can't find the file, so you should know pretty immediately.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I would like to know NOT ONLY if what I wrote is correct but if it is the best practice or there is a better approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185747/setting-the-path-for-include-require-files

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend checking out [Magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)

Example in main.php using **DIR** (the current directory):

```
require_once __DIR__.'/includes/afile.php';
```

Also as you can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php#117921) "require_once" and "require" are language constructs and not functions. Therefore they should be written without "()" brackets!

Comment: so probably I have to `define("ROOT_DIR",__DIR__)` in my main.php and use ROOT_DIR in all other PHP files. Is that correct?