# How to avoid being accessed php script files from users

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess, encryption

In my website I have a simple form running with ajax. And in ajax property `url: '/myfile/script.php'` and that is the whole script file run that form. So if someone access that file using this url: `localhost/myfile/script.php` it can be accessed. But I wants to avoid being happening this.

```html
$.ajax({
    url:"/myfile/script.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:{query:query},  
    success:function(data)
```

this is the ajax script. Please someone guide me through this if there are any methods available.

Comment: You can't. If the user can access it with Ajax, they can access it any other way too. This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info): what's the real problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: Look for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file

Comment: the question is why do you want to avoid that ?

Comment: Check to see if there's and XHR header. That's easy to get around, but it'll stop the casual.

Comment: The basic approach would be "Keep the URL secret". If only the application knows about it, then only the application can make a request to it.

Comment: There's no way to keep the URL secret. The user's device has to know the URL to be able to connect to it, and if the user's device knows the URL, then the user will know it too.