# How to keep a php file from being executed by typing the exact page url

Tags: php, url

I have a php file whose content is like this,
the url to it is "www.xyz.com/abc.php" for example

```
<?php
include "def.php";
echo "something";
?>
```

how can I keep the "def.php" from being excuted when the user typing the url "www.xyz.com/def.php"

Comment: Put it outside of your wwwroot

Comment: Prevent direct access to a php include file: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file

Comment: Thanks very much!