# How to protect php and folder files from unauthorized access?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

1. I want to block direct access to different php files (by writing let's say `http://testpage.com/login_verif.php`), for example the login verification one (that authentificates users).
2. Is it possible for an user to access the `config.php` file that connects him to the mysql database (and has the password written in it)?
3. Also, how can you configure your `uploads` folder, so that an user can only see the image for which he has the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Exit the file if there is no data POSTed to the file, and/or [place the file in a more controlled area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409511/1843510).
2. [You should not have a config.php file - they are very much not safe, but instead environment variables](https://www.codementor.io/ccornutt/keeping-credentials-secure-in-php-kvcbrk55z).
3. You may look into [rewriting to disallow direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236791/1843510), but allow referencing on the domain.

Comment: For problem 1, I already implemented it the first suggestion. Regarding the second idea, I don't know if it doesn't block any kind of access, even from the server itself  (because "Deny from all" sound like it does).

Comment: It would still let you include the file, but nothing else, correct.