# How to create simple prevent direct access to a php include file with .htaccess page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am a newbie to PHP, I would like to create a prevent direct access to a php include file with .htaccess page

```
DemoSite/    <-folder
        index.php
        global_variable.php
        .htaccess
```

I want to prevent direct access `global_variable.php` file

like
`if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( ...`)

Anyidea how to use `.htaccess` to achieve it???

Thank you very much

Comment: No need to use `.htaccess`. Just place the file in a folder outside the web root and load it from there.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file#:~:text=The%20best%20way%20to%20prevent,them%20through%20an%20http%20request.

Comment: or check this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a string  `Deny from all` in  .htaccess file to your include directory

Or

If you want to prevent a file
Then use

```
<Files "global_variable.php">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple practice is adding file to a folder (so the rules just apply to the desired file in folder) and surrounding the folder with this htaccess :

```
Deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from YOUR_SERVER_IP
```

But a better way with php would be to define a value in your index file or any file that is gonna get accessed by user and include or require your desired file, then in it you can check if a value is defined or not, Example :

index.php

```
define('ACCESS', true);
```

global_variable.php

```
defined('ACCESS') or die("No direct access is allowed");
```